# Two concurrent saveAll actions with a unique constraint

Tags: concurrency, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I am not using any type of locking.
Is it possible that two concurrent saveAll requests trying to save the same set of records could collide with each other and both fail ?
There is a unique constraint in the table to avoid duplicacy.

Comment: Which DB engine? And how have you defined the constraint?

Comment: MySQL Inno DB. Unique constraint on 2 colums.